# How to get css class md-inputfield in primeng :- <span class="md-inputfield ">

Tags: angular, primeng

unable to find class **md-inputfield** in primeng.  I need that class attributes to debug the text field. Any hope to get it work properply.

```
<span class="md-inputfield ">
        <input type="text" pInputText [formControl]="bincode" class="input-width">
        <label>Bin Code</label>
      </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have found solution for that While debugging the code. 
The class **md-inputfield** belongs in ultimate/theme.css(premium).  Here i am using nova-light/theme.css, its default theme. So no such classes in default css.